# Why isn't the remote object model creating a record?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, remote-objects

I'm declaring the following in my Visualforce page:

```
<apex:remoteObjects>
    <apex:remoteObjectModel name="Contact" fields="FirstName,LastName,Id">
    </apex:remoteObjectModel>
</apex:remoteObjects>
```

I'm then attempting to create a simple contact record with the following:

```
const data = {
    FirstName: 'Clark',
    LastName: 'Kent'
};
console.log({ data });
const contact = new SObjectModel.Contact(
    data,
    (error, results, event) => {
        console.log({ error, results, event });
    }
);
contact.create();
console.log({ contact });
```

When I load the page, I see the output of the two console logs, with the properties correctly set on the `contact` object, but the callback function is never called and no record is created. No error occurs.

How can I use the remote object model to create contact (and later, other) records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The record is being created, but your callback is in the wrong spot.

```
const data = {
  FirstName: "Clark",
  LastName: "Kent",
};
console.log({ data });
const contact = new SObjectModel.Contact(data);
// Callback goes here
contact.create((error, results, event) => {
  console.log({ error, results, event });
});
console.log({ contact });
```

Comment: I swear, @sfdcfox, sometimes I think you answer all of salesforce.stackexchange.com by yourself. :)

Comment: @Chuck It seems like, doesn't it? I've answered ~10% of all network questions, so I have yet more ground to cover, lol.